# Primality Testing in Java

Tags: java, double, type-conversion, long-integer, pow

So I'm doing some primality testing, using Fermat's test, and also a method I call `Precise`, which takes way too long for large integers, but is a solid reference point to wether my `Fermat` method is right or wrong.
Actually, the only difference between these two methods is that while `Fermat` will check the primality equation (`a^(p-1) % p == 1 % p`) for `k` random a's, `Precise` will check the equation for **all** a's in the interval (`2 <= a <= p-2`).

My problem is, that in order to calculate `a^(p-1)`, I need to use a function that returns an integer (in order to calculate the remainder of the division by `p`), so I guess that `Math.random()` is out of the question.

What should I do? Should I make another method to calculate powers which returns an integer somehow, and if so, how? Is there already such a method?

`Fermat` code:

```
public static boolean Fermat(int p, int k)
{
    int a, i, counter = 0;
    int[] used_a = new int[p-3];

    a = (int) (Math.random() * (p-1) + 2);
    for(i=0;i<k;i++){
        used_a[counter] = a;
        if(Math.pow(a, p-1) % p != 1 % p){
            return false;
        }
        while((contains(used_a, a)) && (counter < p-4)){ // contains(int[] array, int key) is just a method which tells us if key is in the array
            a = (int) (Math.random() * (p-1) + 2);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`Precise` code:

```
public static boolean Precise(int p)
{
    int a;

    for(a=2;a<=p-2;a++){
        if(Math.pow(a, p-1) % p != 1 % p){
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `Precise` and `Fermat`?

Comment: What's the deal with all these tags, e.g. long-integer, you're not asking about/using long integers in your code? Anyway, have you considered `java.util.Random` for generating int's?

Comment: @Linus my problem is that I don't have a power method that returns an int. As for the long ints, fermat's test's purpose is to verify large prime numbers, so that's why I put those tags.

Comment: Yes, you should probably write your own integer power method, though you should probably write it to do power and modulus at the same time.  You could certainly do that the obvious way, e.g. just by multiplying a number by itself the appropriate number of times.  (Or you could just use `BigInteger.isProbablePrime`, which solves the whole problem for you.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks! Well, the whole purpose of this is to write a program to search for probable primes, so I can't just call a method that does it for me.

Comment: @jimkokko5, Well if they are truly **large** numbers then you should be using [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) not `int` or `long`, and by the way it has an integral power method as well... good luck.